# How can I upgrade Graylog2 to a newer version?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, upgrade, graylog2

I have not been able to find documentation on how to upgrade Graylog2 to a new version. I am currently on v0.20.1 and would like to go up to .6.

I am using both the server and web interface, so steps for both would be very helpful!

I am running it on an AWS image, which I originally got from here: http://www.itoc.com.au/blog/graylog2-one-click-deploy-ami-for-aws-cloud-released-and-updated-today

I don't want to rebuild/recreate my database, etc. And I haven't seen a good way to port my data from one Graylog server to another, otherwise I could just spin up a new version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading from 0.x to 0.x the needed work for the upgrade is minimal:

1. Backup your /etc/graylog2.conf file `cp /etc/graylog2.conf /etc/graylog.conf.backup`
2. Untar the new version of graylog2 `tar xvf graylog-x-x-x.tar`
3. Browse inside the new graylog2 folder
4. Copy the graylog2.conf.example to /etc/graylog2.conf `cp graylog2.conf.example /etc/graylog2.conf` (**yes** to overwrite)
5. Compare between the file that you backed up in step 1 and the new file at /etc/graylo2.conf
6. Define the new graylog2 as a service
7. Run the new installed graylog2 with: service start graylog2

Hope I could help with this issue